# Django Rest Framework: return ForeignKey as array, getting "TypeError: object is not iterable"?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a slightly awkward Django Rest Framework question (I want to do something "wrong", for consistency with an existing data format, and I wonder if DRF will force me to do it "right").

I am working with Django 1.7 and the DRF, upgrading an existing Piston API. I have a working API call that I need to tweak slightly to match the way Piston returned it.

These are the underlying models:

```
class Hundred(models.Model):
    id = models.SlugField(unique=True, primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Place(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    hundred = models.ForeignKey(Hundred, null=True,
                                related_name='places_in_hundred')
    vill = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

My API lets users query by places in a bounding box, and it currently returns the hundred for each place as a dictionary:

```
[{
  id: 1008,
  vill: "Stanton",
  hundred: {
    id: "Uxbridge"
  }
} ...
```

But I need to return it as an array, to match my existing Piston logic:

```
[{
  id: 1008,
  vill: "Stanton",
  hundred: [{
    id: "Uxbridge"
  }]
} ...
```

I know this isn't logically correct (there's only one Hundred per Place) but the clients for my API will be expecting an array, so I need to continue to return one.

Currently this is my views code:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def place(request, id):
    myplace = Place.objects.get(id=id)
    serializer = PlaceSerializer(myplace)
    return JSONResponse(serializer.data)
```

And this is my serializer code:

```
class _HundredIdSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Hundred
        fields = ('id',)

class PlaceSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    hundred = _HundredIdSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Place
        fields = ('id', 'vill', 'hundred', )
```

The first thing I tried was to add `many=True` to the definition of hundred in my `PlaceSerializer` (i.e. `hundred = _HundredIdSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)`), but that gives me an error:

```
 TypeError at /api/1.0/placesnear/: 'Hundred' object is not iterable
```

Is there any way I can change the serializer to return an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to change the serializer. Just make the required change in the views:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
def place(request, id):
    myplace = Place.objects.get(id=id)
    serializer = PlaceSerializer(myplace)
    data = serializer.data
    data['hundred'] = [data['hundred']]
    return JSONResponse(data)
```